# how to pass many value in command line (when calling the programme) then use those value as input function value

Tags: python, input, command-line

Here an example

**program1.py**

```
n=input("enter any data")
print(n)
```

Execute it

```
python3 program1.py "Hello World!"
```

output:

```
Hello World!
```

Here the user don't type any value .The program took value given in commandline as #input() value

So how can I achieve it?

Comment: `v = input("Information here"); while v != "done": results.append(v); v = input("Information here:")`

Comment: @LarrytheLlama No, you missed the point.  He wants input from the command line, NOT from the terminal.

Comment: @TimRoberts Actually, in my opinion, it is not clear if they want to take CLI argument and completely remove terminal input from user or they want to take user input only when there is no CLI argument.

Answer (score 0):

The command line arguments are delivered in the `sys.argv` list.  The first entry is the name of the script itself (`program1.py` in your example.

```
import sys
print( sys.argv[1] )
```

If you pass multiple words, they'll come in the rest of the list.  So, for example:

```
import sys
print( ''.join(sys.argv[1:])
```

Output:

```
$ python program1.py this is a test
this is a test
$
```